# erase template cache

Tags: python, django, django-cache, django-caching

I have a Django app where users can select between 2 interface modes, that mode affect some pages... for those pages I use different templates

In urls.py I have something like this:

```
mode = Config.objects.get().mode
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^my_url/$', 'custom_view', {'template':'my_template.html', 'mode':mode} ),
)
```

Then my view is something like this:

```
@render_to()
def custom_view(request, template, mg=False, login=True):
    if mode:
        template = template + 'x' #I add an x to the template name to advice to django I that it should use the mode_2 template.
    return {'TEMPLATE':template}
```

My problem is when the user selects mode 2 (in my custom Configuration page), mode does not change until server is restarted (either apache or runserver.py is the same).

I think this has to do something with cache, but I can't find how to erase that cache. (each time Config.mode is changed.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Getting the mode in urls.py is not going to work. The `get` will only be executed once, when the file is first imported.

Do the database work in the view function, instead.

Comment: +1. `urls.py` is loaded only once. It is not the best place for dynamic configuration.

Comment: +1. We have a `startup.py` which is imported by `urls.py` and used to contain the one-time startup script.